# How can I get the name of the thread by knowing the thread id?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am working on a multithread traceback script, I am using the following code sample to retrieve the name of the thread, is there a nicer way to get the name of the thread out of the thread id?

```
for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        tname = "None"
        for mthread in threading.enumerate():
            if mthread.ident == threadId:
                tname = mthread.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the public interface of `threading`. Internally, `threading` maintains exactly the mapping you want, so you could write (at your own risk)

```
def thread_for_ident(ident):
    return threading._active.get(ident)
```

which will return `None` if there is no such thread. I don't think you're solution is actually too bad as long as there aren't many threads.